# How to define findAll for html nested tags using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Given

```
<a href="www.example.com/"></a>

<table class="theclass">
<tr><td>
<a href="www.example.com/two">two</a>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<a href ="www.example.com/three">three</a>
<span>blabla<span>
</td></td>
</table>
```

How can I scrape only the   that is inside table class="the class"? I tried using

```
soup = util.mysoupopen(theexample) 
infoText = soup.findAll("table", {"class": "the class"})
```

but I did not know how to further define the finding statement. Something else I tried, was turning the result of findAll() into an array. Then looking for patterns of when the needle would show up, but I couldnt find a consistent pattern.
Thanks

Comment: what do you want to scrap? you said "How can I scrape only the that is inside table class="the class"?" did you mean the links?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question. That's the python code which should work. Iterating to find all tables with the class="theclass", then finding links inside.

```
>>> foo = """<a href="www.example.com/"></a>
... <table class="theclass">
... <tr><td>
... <a href="www.example.com/two">two</a>
... </td></tr>
... <tr><td>
... <a href ="www.example.com/three">three</a>
... <span>blabla<span>
... </td></td>
... </table>
... """
>>> import BeautifulSoup as bs
>>> soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(foo)
>>> for table in soup.findAll('table', {'class':'theclass'} ):
...     links=table.findAll('a')
... 
>>> print links
[<a href="www.example.com/two">two</a>, <a href="www.example.com/three">three</a>]
```

Answer (score 2):

infoText is a list. You should iterate over it.

```
>>>for info in infoText:
>>>    print info.tr.td.a
<a href="www.example.com/two">two</a>
```

Then you can access the `<table>` element. If you are just expecting one table element with a class "theclass" in your document, `soup.find("table", {"class": "the class"})` would give you the table directly.

Comment: I got this error, and I have no clue why that is. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    print info.tr.td.a
  File "/nfs/home/j/d/jdiaz/cs171/BeautifulSoup.py", line 402, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError, "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, attr)
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'tr'`